# Issue with Sequential Touch Points in Using CALayer for Drawing in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, draw, calayer

I'm encountering an issue with my drawing functionality in Swift, specifically when using CALayer instead of UIBezierPath. Here's the problem I'm facing:

I am creating a texture from an image and using the texture to create a drawing line through finger stroke. In this process, the line is being created by joining the texture one by one, side by side. Initially, I used UIBezierPath for drawing, and everything worked fine. However, when I switched to using CALayer for drawing, for using textures to draw lines, I noticed that the touch points are not sequentially joining or increasing if I move my finger fast.
[image: drawing speed]

When I move my finger slowly, the drawing works fine, and the touch points are joining sequentially.
However, when I move my finger fast, the touch points seem to skip, resulting in disjointed lines and multiple blank spaces within a line.

```
class CustomStrokeDrawingView: UIView {
    var path = UIBezierPath()
    var startPoint = CGPoint()
    var touchPoint = CGPoint()
    var shape =  UIImage(named:"square-outline")

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        let touch = touches.first
        if let point = touch?.location(in: self) {
            startPoint = point
        }
    }

    override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        let touch = touches.first
        if let point = touch?.location(in: self) {
            touchPoint = point
        }

        let imageLayer = CALayer()
        imageLayer.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        imageLayer.bounds = CGRect(x: startPoint.x, y: startPoint.y , width: 20, height: 20)
        imageLayer.position = CGPoint(x:touchPoint.x ,y:touchPoint.y)
        imageLayer.contents = shape?.cgImage
        self.layer.addSublayer(imageLayer)
        
        
    }
    
    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        super.draw(rect)
    }
}
```

Comment: *"when I move my finger fast, the touch points seem to skip"* -- yes, you can move your finger ***much faster*** than iOS can trigger the `touchesMoved` event. If you want a "filled in line" - with multiple copies of your image - you will need a different approach.

Answer (score 1):

It is very easy to move your finger faster than iOS can generate `touchesMoved` events ... if you log the points with `print()` statements, you can easily see this in the debug console. It's possible to "swipe" fast enough across the device screen and only generate 2 or 3 points.

One approach is to interpolate *n*-number of points on the lines between the `touchesMoved` points, and then draw your shape image at each of those points.

Here's some quick example code...

---

**UIView subclass**

```
class CustomStrokeDrawingView: UIView {
    
    var shape: UIImage!
    var pts: [CGPoint] = []

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }
    func commonInit() {
        // crash if we can't load the "brush" image
        guard let img =  UIImage(named:"square-outline") else {
            fatalError("Could not load shape image!")
        }
        shape = img
    }
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        let touch = touches.first
        if let startPoint = touch?.location(in: self) {
            // reset points array to only the starting point
            //print("Start:", startPoint)
            pts = [startPoint]
        }
    }
    
    override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        let touch = touches.first
        if let touchPoint = touch?.location(in: self) {
            //print("Moved:", touchPoint)
            pts.append(touchPoint)
            // trigger draw()
            setNeedsDisplay()
        }
    }

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        super.draw(rect)
        
        guard pts.count > 1 else { return }

        let shapeSize: CGSize = shape.size
        
        // adjust as desired
        let pixelsPerIteration: CGFloat = 5.0

        for idx in 0..<(pts.count - 1) {
            
            let startx: CGFloat = pts[idx].x
            let starty: CGFloat = pts[idx].y
            let dx: CGFloat = pts[idx+1].x - startx
            let dy: CGFloat = pts[idx+1].y - starty
            
            let distance: CGFloat = sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy)
            let iterations = distance / pixelsPerIteration + 1
            let dxIncrement = dx / iterations
            let dyIncrement = dy / iterations
            
            var dstRect: CGRect = .init(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: shapeSize.width, height: shapeSize.height)
            
            var x: CGFloat = startx - shapeSize.width / 2.0
            var y: CGFloat = starty - shapeSize.height / 2.0
            
            // draw a series of shape images to form the line
            for _ in 0..<Int(iterations) {
                dstRect.origin.x = x
                dstRect.origin.y = y
                x += dxIncrement
                y += dyIncrement
                shape.draw(in: dstRect)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Example controller class**

```
class DrawTestVC: UIViewController {
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: false)
        
        view.backgroundColor = .systemYellow
        
        let drawView = CustomStrokeDrawingView()
        drawView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(drawView)
        
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            drawView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            drawView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            drawView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -20.0),
            drawView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.bottomAnchor, constant: -20.0),
        ])
        
        drawView.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0.95, alpha: 1.0)
    }
    
}
```

---

Looks about like this:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! Your solution resolved my issue perfectly. I've marked it as the accepted answer and upvoted it. I really appreciate the time you took to assist me. I'll be sure to keep an eye on this thread and update it if I encounter any related problems in the future. Thanks again!